# SVG not showing up in Safari [React]

Tags: html, reactjs, svg, safari

I have an SVG that I am trying to display. It is just a simple functional component, shown here:

```
export const GoIcon = () => (
    <svg viewBox="0 0 128 128" type="image/svg+xml" height="128" width="128">
        <g>
            <defs>
                <path id="a" d="M18.8 1h90.5v126h-90.5z"></path>
            </defs>
            <clipPath id="b">
                <use xlinkHref="#a" overflow="visible"></use>
            </clipPath>
            <path
                fillRule="evenodd"
                clipRule="evenodd"
                fill="#F6D2A2"
                d="M21.1 68.7c.2 3.5 3.7 1.9 5.3.8 1.5-1.1 2-.2 2.1-2.3.1-1.4.2-2.7.2-4.1-2.3-.2-4.8.3-6.7 1.7-.9.7-2.8 3-.9 3.9"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                d="M23 71.2c-.7 0-2-.3-2.2-2.3-.6-.4-.8-.9-.8-1.2-.1-1.2 1.2-2.6 1.9-3.1 1.6-1.2 3.7-1.8 5.9-1.8h1.3v.3c.1 1.1 0 2.2-.1 3.2 0 .3 0 .6-.1.9-.1 1.5-.4 1.7-1.1 2-.3.1-.6.2-1.1.6-.5.3-2.2 1.4-3.7 1.4zm4.8-7.8c-2.1 0-4 .6-5.5 1.7-.7.5-1.7 1.7-1.6 2.5 0 .3.2.6.6.8l.2.1v.2c.1 1.6.9 1.8 1.5 1.8 1 0 2.4-.7 3.3-1.3.6-.4 1-.5 1.3-.6.5-.2.6-.2.7-1.4 0-.3 0-.6.1-.9.1-.9.1-1.9.1-2.8-.3-.1-.5-.1-.7-.1z"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                fillRule="evenodd"
                clipRule="evenodd"
                fill="#C6B198"
                d="M21.1 68.7c.5-.2 1.1-.3 1.4-.8"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                d="M21.1 69c-.1 0-.3-.1-.3-.2-.1-.2 0-.4.2-.4.1 0 .2-.1.2-.1.4-.2.8-.3 1-.6.1-.1.3-.2.5-.1.1.1.2.3.1.5-.4.5-.9.7-1.3.8l-.2.1h-.2z"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                fillRule="evenodd"
                clipRule="evenodd"
                fill="#6AD7E5"
                d="M29.3 26.4c-13.6-3.8-3.5-21.1 7.4-14l-7.4 14z"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                d="M29.5 26.8l-.3-.1c-7-2-6.9-7-6.7-8.5.5-3.8 4.1-7.8 8.9-7.8 1.9 0 3.7.6 5.5 1.8l.3.2-7.7 14.4zm1.9-15.7c-4.5 0-7.8 3.7-8.3 7.2-.5 3.6 1.7 6.4 6 7.7l7.1-13.5c-1.5-.9-3.1-1.4-4.8-1.4z"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                fillRule="evenodd"
                clipRule="evenodd"
                fill="#6AD7E5"
                d="M89.6 11.1c10.7-7.5 20.5 9.5 8 13.8l-8-13.8z"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                d="M97.5 25.3l-8.3-14.3.3-.2c1.9-1.3 3.8-2 5.7-2 4.6 0 7.9 3.8 8.6 7.5.3 1.5.6 6.6-6 8.8l-.3.2zm-7.4-14l7.7 13.3c3.9-1.4 5.9-4.4 5.3-8-.6-3.4-3.7-6.9-7.9-6.9-1.7-.1-3.4.4-5.1 1.6z"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                fillRule="evenodd"
                clipRule="evenodd"
                fill="#F6D2A2"
                d="M92 112.3c2.7 1.7 7.7 6.8 3.6 9.3-3.9 3.6-6.1-4-9.6-5 1.5-2 3.4-3.9 6-4.3"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                d="M93.5 122.9c-1.6 0-3-1.6-4.2-3.1-1.1-1.2-2.2-2.5-3.4-2.9l-.5-.1.3-.4c1.2-1.7 3.2-3.9 6.2-4.4h.1l.1.1c1.7 1.1 5.4 4.2 5.3 7.1 0 1.1-.6 2-1.7 2.7-.7.7-1.4 1-2.2 1zm-7-6.5c1.2.5 2.2 1.8 3.2 2.9 1.2 1.5 2.4 2.8 3.7 2.8.6 0 1.2-.3 1.8-.9h.1c.9-.6 1.4-1.3 1.4-2.2 0-2.3-2.9-5.2-4.9-6.5-1.8.5-3.6 1.7-5.3 3.9zM95.6 121.9c-.1 0-.2-.1-.3-.2-.2-.4-.4-.9-.5-1.3-.3-.8-.6-1.6-1.2-2.2-.1-.1-.1-.3 0-.5.1-.1.3-.1.5 0 .7.7 1.1 1.6 1.4 2.5l.5 1.2c.1.2 0 .4-.1.5h-.3z"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                fillRule="evenodd"
                clipRule="evenodd"
                fill="#F6D2A2"
                d="M43.2 118.1c-3.2.5-5 3.4-7.7 4.9-2.5 1.5-3.5-.5-3.7-.9-.4-.2-.4.2-1-.4-2.3-3.7 2.4-6.4 4.9-8.2 3.5-.8 5.7 2.2 7.5 4.6"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                d="M33.8 123.8c-1.3 0-2-1.1-2.2-1.5h-.1c-.3 0-.5-.1-.9-.5v-.1c-2.2-3.5 1.6-6.2 4.1-8l.9-.6h.2c.4-.1.7-.1 1.1-.1 3 0 4.9 2.6 6.5 4.7l.5.7-.6.1c-1.9.3-3.3 1.5-4.7 2.7-.9.8-1.8 1.5-2.8 2.1-.8.3-1.4.5-2 .5zm-2.2-2.1c.1 0 .2 0 .4.1h.1l.1.1c.2.3.7 1.2 1.7 1.2.5 0 1-.2 1.5-.5 1-.5 1.9-1.3 2.7-2 1.3-1.1 2.7-2.3 4.5-2.8-1.5-2-3.3-4.2-5.8-4.2-.3 0-.6 0-.9.1l-.8.6c-2.6 1.8-5.8 4.1-3.9 7.1.1.2.2.3.4.3zM31.8 122.4c-.2 0-.4-.2-.3-.4.1-1 .6-1.7 1.1-2.5.3-.4.5-.8.7-1.2.1-.2.3-.2.4-.2.2.1.2.3.2.4-.2.5-.5.9-.8 1.3-.5.7-.9 1.3-1 2.1 0 .4-.1.5-.3.5z"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                fillRule="evenodd"
                clipRule="evenodd"
                d="M29.9 21.7c-1.8-.9-3.1-2.2-2-4.3 1-1.9 2.9-1.7 4.7-.8l-2.7 5.1zM94.8 19.9c1.8-.9 3.1-2.2 2-4.3-1-1.9-2.9-1.7-4.7-.8l2.7 5.1z"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                fillRule="evenodd"
                clipRule="evenodd"
                fill="#F6D2A2"
                d="M107.1 68.2c-.2 3.5-3.7 1.9-5.3.8-1.5-1.1-2-.2-2.1-2.3-.1-1.4-.2-2.7-.2-4.1 2.3-.2 4.8.3 6.7 1.7 1 .8 2.8 3 .9 3.9"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                d="M105.3 70.7c-1.5 0-3.2-1.1-3.7-1.4-.5-.3-.8-.5-1.1-.6-.8-.3-1-.5-1.1-2 0-.3 0-.6-.1-.9-.1-1-.2-2.1-.1-3.2v-.3h1.3c2.2 0 4.3.6 5.9 1.8.7.5 2 1.9 1.9 3.1 0 .4-.2.9-.8 1.2-.2 2-1.5 2.3-2.2 2.3zm-5.5-7.7c0 .9 0 1.9.1 2.8 0 .3 0 .6.1.9.1 1.2.2 1.2.7 1.4.3.1.7.3 1.3.6.9.6 2.3 1.3 3.3 1.3.6 0 1.4-.2 1.5-1.8v-.2l.2-.1c.4-.2.6-.4.6-.8.1-.8-.9-2-1.6-2.5-1.5-1.1-3.5-1.7-5.5-1.7-.2.1-.4.1-.7.1z"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                fillRule="evenodd"
                clipRule="evenodd"
                fill="#C6B198"
                d="M107.1 68.2c-.5-.2-1.1-.3-1.4-.8"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                d="M107.1 68.6h-.1l-.2-.1c-.5-.2-1-.3-1.3-.8-.1-.1-.1-.4.1-.5.1-.1.4-.1.5.1.2.3.6.4 1 .6.1 0 .2.1.2.1.2.1.3.3.2.4-.1.1-.3.2-.4.2z"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                fillRule="evenodd"
                clipRule="evenodd"
                fill="#6AD7E5"
                d="M62.8 4c13.6 0 26.3 1.9 33 15 6 14.6 3.8 30.4 4.8 45.9.8 13.3 2.5 28.6-3.6 40.9-6.5 12.9-22.7 16.2-36 15.7-10.5-.4-23.1-3.8-29.1-13.4-6.9-11.2-3.7-27.9-3.2-40.4.6-14.8-4-29.7.9-44.1 4.9-15.1 18.5-18.5 33.2-19.6"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                d="M63.3 121.9h-2.5c-4.1-.1-10.3-.8-16.4-3.3-5.9-2.4-10.2-5.8-13-10.3-5.6-9.1-4.6-21.6-3.7-32.7.2-2.8.4-5.4.5-7.9.2-5.2-.2-10.6-.7-15.7-.8-9.4-1.6-19.1 1.5-28.5 2.4-7 6.7-12 13.2-15.2 5.1-2.5 11.4-3.9 20.4-4.6 13.4-.1 26.7 1.8 33.4 15.1 4.4 10.7 4.4 22.2 4.5 33.3 0 4.2 0 8.5.3 12.7.1 1.3.2 2.6.2 3.9.8 12.2 1.7 26-3.9 37.2-2.8 5.7-7.7 9.9-14.4 12.6-5.4 2.2-12.2 3.4-19.4 3.4zm-.5-117.6c-14.1 1.1-27.9 4.2-33 19.4-3.1 9.3-2.3 18.9-1.5 28.2.4 5.2.9 10.5.7 15.8-.1 2.5-.3 5.1-.5 7.9-.9 11-1.9 23.4 3.6 32.3 2.3 3.7 9.7 12.5 28.8 13.2h2.5c22.1 0 30.3-9.8 33.3-15.6 5.5-11 4.6-24.8 3.9-36.9-.1-1.3-.2-2.6-.2-3.9-.2-4.2-.3-8.5-.3-12.7-.1-11-.1-22.5-4.4-33.1-3-5.9-7.5-9.9-13.7-12.2-6.4-2.1-13.6-2.4-19.2-2.4z"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                fillRule="evenodd"
                clipRule="evenodd"
                fill="#fff"
                d="M65.2 22.2c2.4 14.2 25.6 10.4 22.3-3.9-3-12.8-23.1-9.2-22.3 3.9"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                d="M76.2 31.5c-4.5 0-10.2-2.4-11.4-9.2-.2-3.2.8-6.1 2.9-8.3 2.3-2.5 5.8-3.9 9.4-3.9 4.2 0 9.2 2.2 10.6 8.3.8 3.4.2 6.4-1.7 8.8-2.1 2.6-5.8 4.3-9.8 4.3zm-10.7-9.3c.5 2.8 1.8 5 3.9 6.6 1.8 1.4 4.3 2.1 6.8 2.1 3.7 0 7.3-1.6 9.3-4.1 1.8-2.2 2.3-5.1 1.6-8.3-1.3-5.7-6-7.7-10-7.7-3.4 0-6.7 1.4-8.9 3.7-1.9 2-2.9 4.7-2.7 7.7z"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                fillRule="evenodd"
                clipRule="evenodd"
                fill="#fff"
                d="M37.5 24.5c3.2 12.3 22.9 9.2 22.2-3.2-.9-14.8-25.3-12-22.2 3.2"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                d="M48 32.7c-4.3 0-9.3-2.1-10.9-8.1-.7-3.5 0-6.7 2-9.1 2.2-2.7 5.8-4.3 9.7-4.3 5.2 0 10.7 3.1 11.1 10.1.2 2.9-.7 5.5-2.7 7.6-2.1 2.3-5.6 3.8-9.2 3.8zm.8-20.8c-3.7 0-7.1 1.5-9.2 4-1.9 2.3-2.5 5.2-1.8 8.5 1.4 5.6 6.2 7.6 10.2 7.6 3.4 0 6.7-1.3 8.8-3.6 1.8-1.9 2.7-4.4 2.5-7.1-.2-4.3-3.1-9.4-10.5-9.4z"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                fillRule="evenodd"
                clipRule="evenodd"
                fill="#fff"
                d="M68 39.2c0 1.8.4 3.9.1 5.9-.5.9-1.4 1-2.2 1.3-1.1-.2-2-.9-2.5-1.9-.3-2.2.1-4.4.2-6.6l4.4 1.3z"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                d="M65.9 46.8c-1.3-.2-2.3-1-2.8-2.1-.2-1.6-.1-3.1 0-4.6.1-.7.1-1.4.1-2.1v-.4l5.1 1.6v.2c0 .6.1 1.2.1 1.9.1 1.3.2 2.7 0 4v.1c-.4.8-1.1 1-1.8 1.3-.2-.1-.4 0-.7.1zm-2.2-2.4c.4.9 1.2 1.5 2.1 1.7.2-.1.4-.1.5-.2.6-.2 1.1-.4 1.4-.9.2-1.2.1-2.5 0-3.8 0-.6-.1-1.2-.1-1.7l-3.8-1.2c0 .6-.1 1.2-.1 1.7-.1 1.6-.2 3 0 4.4z"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                fillRule="evenodd"
                clipRule="evenodd"
                d="M46.3 22.5c0 2-1.5 3.6-3.3 3.6-1.8 0-3.3-1.6-3.3-3.6s1.5-3.6 3.3-3.6c1.8 0 3.3 1.6 3.3 3.6"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                fillRule="evenodd"
                clipRule="evenodd"
                fill="#fff"
                d="M45.2 23.3c0 .5-.4.9-.8.9s-.8-.4-.8-.9.4-.9.8-.9c.5 0 .8.4.8.9"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                fillRule="evenodd"
                clipRule="evenodd"
                d="M74.2 21.6c0 2-1.5 3.6-3.3 3.6-1.8 0-3.3-1.6-3.3-3.6s1.5-3.6 3.3-3.6c1.8 0 3.3 1.6 3.3 3.6"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                fillRule="evenodd"
                clipRule="evenodd"
                fill="#fff"
                d="M73.2 22.4c0 .5-.3.9-.8.9-.4 0-.8-.4-.8-.9s.3-.9.8-.9c.4 0 .8.4.8.9"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                fillRule="evenodd"
                clipRule="evenodd"
                fill="#fff"
                d="M58.4 39c-1.5 3.5.8 10.6 4.8 5.4-.3-2.2.1-4.4.2-6.6l-5 1.2z"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                d="M60.5 46.6c-.7 0-1.4-.4-1.9-1.2-1.1-1.6-1.3-4.6-.5-6.5l.1-.2 5.5-1.4v.4l-.1 2.2c-.1 1.5-.2 2.9 0 4.4v.1l-.1.1c-1 1.4-2 2.1-3 2.1zm-1.8-7.3c-.6 1.7-.4 4.4.5 5.7.4.6.8.9 1.3.9.7 0 1.5-.6 2.3-1.6-.2-1.5-.1-3 .1-4.4l.1-1.7-4.3 1.1z"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                fillRule="evenodd"
                clipRule="evenodd"
                fill="#F6D2A2"
                d="M58.9 32.2c-2.7.2-4.9 3.5-3.5 6 1.9 3.4 6-.3 8.6 0 3 .1 5.4 3.2 7.8.6 2.7-2.9-1.2-5.7-4.1-7l-8.8.4z"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                fill="#231F20"
                d="M69.7 40.2c-.9 0-1.8-.4-2.7-.8-.9-.4-1.9-.8-3-.8h-.3c-.8 0-1.7.3-2.7.7-1.1.4-2.2.7-3.2.7-1.2 0-2.1-.5-2.7-1.6-.7-1.2-.6-2.6.1-3.9.8-1.5 2.2-2.4 3.7-2.6l8.9-.4h.1c2.2.9 4.7 2.6 5.2 4.6.2 1-.1 2-.9 2.9-.8.9-1.6 1.2-2.5 1.2zm-5.6-2.2c1.1 0 2.2.5 3.2.9.9.4 1.7.7 2.5.7.7 0 1.3-.3 1.9-.9.7-.7.9-1.5.8-2.3-.4-1.7-2.8-3.3-4.7-4.1l-8.7.4c-1.3.1-2.5 1-3.2 2.2-.6 1.1-.6 2.3-.1 3.3.5.9 1.1 1.3 2.1 1.3.9 0 1.9-.4 2.9-.7 1.1-.4 2-.7 3-.7 0-.2.1-.2.3-.1z"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
            <path
                fillRule="evenodd"
                clipRule="evenodd"
                d="M58.6 32.1c-.2-4.7 8.8-5.3 9.8-1.4 1.1 4-9.4 4.9-9.8 1.4"
                clipPath="url(#b)"></path>
        </g>
    </svg>
);
```

I have been trying and failing to get it to display on Safari. It displays on Google Chrome perfectly fine. Because I am using React, I changed some tags such as `xlink:href` to `xlinkHref`, `fill-rule` to `fillRule`, and `clip-rule` to `clipRule`.

Here is what I have tried:
1.) Setting `xlink:href` to `href`
2.) Adding a `type` to the outer SVG (still there)
3.) Adding a `height` and `width` to the outer SVG (still there).

I am simply trying to display the blue Golang icon from https://devicon.dev/,

I couldn't seem to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated!

I tried changing `xlink:href` to simply `href`

Comment: Here's what I would try - get rid of the type, keep xlink:href. Keep the explicit sizing - but make it 128px. Move your clip path definition into the defs element. Change the use element in the clip path into a normal shape and get rid of the overflow (only symbol/use, image, foreignObject, pattern and marker SVG sub-elements support an overflow property).

Comment: @MichaelMullany That did not work.

Comment: Do you have duplicate ID's somewhere? - This is displaying ok in Safari when I convert it to regular SVG. If you delete all the path elements and put, let's say, a simple circle element in the content - do you still have a problem?